# How to split string using scala?

Tags: string, scala, split

I have a following string and I want to split it using scala

```
"myInfo": "myName-name;model-R210;"
```

I want to split value of myInfo string such that I can access myName and its value seperately.
e.g. myName:name, model:R210 etc

I am using following code to split string -

```
(mainString \ "myInfo").as[String].split("\\;").toList.map(_.split("\\-"))
```

where mainString is Json and contains 'myInfo' key value pair.

How do I split string to seperate it by '-' and access it?

Comment: What do you mean by `access myName and its value seperately`? Do you want to keep them in tuples? Like `((myName, name), (model, R210))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain a `Map[String,String]` like so:

```
val data: Map[String,String] = (mainString \ "myInfo").as[String]
    .split("\\;").map(_.split("\\-").toList)
    .collect { 
      case key :: value :: _ => key -> value
    }.toMap
```

Then access your values:

```
val name = data.getOrElse("myName", "DefaultNameIfMissing")
```

Comment: Exactly what I wants.. How do I access 'myName' from that list?

Comment: What if I don't want to use .getOrElse method

Comment: What if I don't want to use .getOrElse method. I have a field that contains integer field. when I use data.get("cNumber"), It returns string. Is there any way to return Int value

Comment: @Vishwas: I'd recommend you read up on Scala's `Map` and `Option` types and ask another question if necessary. If you want an int from a `Map[String,String]` you can do something like `data.get("someInt").map(_.toInt).getOrElse(0)`.

Comment: Hi @Mikesname I'm using a similar strategy to split my file String into object Map see [Scala immutable Map slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053215/). But is really slow. Can be faster if we convert to Array[(String, String)]?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, shame on whoever encoded a complex data structure into a string in a JSON document; you shouldn't have to parse it at all.  If it's under your control, I'd change that to something like

```
"myInfo": {
  "myName": "name",
  "model": "R210"
}
```

But if you can't change the input, then just do this to get the Map you want:

```
val myInfo = ((mainString \ "myInfo").as[String] split ';' map (_ split '-') collect { case Array(k,v) => k->v } ).toMap
```

No need to create Lists out of the intermediate results -- that would just slow things down.  And just split on a Char, not a String (which would get compiled as a regular expression).

Note that the `collect` causes any component with no hyphen or more than one hyphen to be ignored; you might want to do something else there.