# Scala immutable Map slow

Tags: java, performance, scala, functional-programming, bigdata

I have a piece of code when I create a map like:

```
 val map = gtfLineArr(8).split(";").map(_ split "\"").collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }.toMap
```

Then I use this map to create my object:

```
case class MyObject(val attribute1: String, val attribute2: Map[String:String])
```

I'm reading millions of lines and converting to MyObjects using an iterator. Like

```
MyObject("1", map)
```

When I do it is really slow, more than 1h for 2'000'000 entries.

I remove the map from the object creation, but still I do the split process (section 1):

```
val map = gtfLineArr(8).split(";").map(_ split "\"").collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }.toMap
MyObject("1", null)
```

And the process the script run in less than 1 min. for the 2'000'000 millions entries.

I di'd some profiling and looks like is when the object is created the assignment between the `val map` to the object map is making the process slow. What I' missing?

**Update to explain better the problem:**

If you see my code the to explain my self iterate over 2000000 lines converting each line to an internal objet, to iterate I do:

```
it.map(cretateNewObject).toList
```

this iterator iterate through all the lines and convert them to my objects using the function `createNewObject`.

This is actually really fast, specially using big memory as dk14 said.  The performance problem is inside my

```
`crateNewObject(val line:String)`
```

this function create an object

```
`class MyObject(val attribute1:String, val attribute2:Map[String, String])`
```

the my function take the line and do first

```
`val attributeArr = line.split("\t")`
```

the first attribute record of the array is the attribute1 of my object and the second attribute is

```
`val map = attributeArr(8).split(";").map(_ split "\"").collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }.toMap`
```

if I only print the number of elements in map the programs end in 2 min, if I pass map to my new object line `MyObject(attribute1, map)` the program is really slow.

Comment: In the second case you probably don't use `val map` anywhere, so the compiler just throws the code in that line away and doesn't split anything.

Comment: Hi @kolman Is not the case because the `gtfLineArr(8).split(";").map(_ split "\"").collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }.toMap` compute the split and convert the result to a Map. Actually, I did `gtfLineArr(8).split(";").map(_ split "\"").collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }.toMap.size` and print the results and is a minute that means the Map is created. My suspicious is that when the map is passed to the new object is doing "some" transformation that is creating the issue.

Comment: What else is your code doing? The time is probably not spent int these lines.

Comment: Dima Not really. As I said. When I remove the assignment of the map onto the constructor by null. Then the program is really fast.

Comment: just try `(0 to 2000000).toList` vs `(0 to 2000000).map(x => x -> x).toMap` to get pure results

Comment: @ypriverol I've noticed that `toMap` is much more hard on memory, so you might try to increase the memory with `-Xms`/`-Xmx`

Comment: Sorry dk14 I don't get your point

Comment: @ypriverol I explained it in the answer, `toMap` is repeatedly (2000000 times) doing `updated0`, which in its turn doing an `Array.copy` pretty often, which requires lots of memory allocations, which causes GC to go MarkAndSweep (slow garbage collection) most of the time

Comment: Is `breakOut` not an option? `val map: Map[String, String] = gtfLineArr(8).split(";").map(_ split "\"").collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }(collection.breakOut)` should be faster as it builds a map right away instead of building a `Seq` of tuples and then converting it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the signature of your Object, there might be an implicit conversion.

Comment: `class MyObject(val attribute1:String, val attribute2: Map[String, String])`

Comment: @SaschaKolberg the val map:Map[String, String] = gtfLineArr(8).split(";").map(_ split "\"").collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }(collection.breakOut) is also slow.

Comment: What you mean is that map.size only will give the total number of objects to be allocated. But just when we create the new object is when the map allocation is performed and this is why is saw slow?.

Comment: @ypriverol Are you doing something with your `MyObject(...)` after creation (like logging or anythin). Because only thing that makes a difference here is that you 1) don't allow `map` to be collected before MyObject; 2) All implicit conversions from `map` to string are also going to be slow

Comment: No, just print the final size of the list of the new objects. Listofneobjects.size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(0 to 2000000).toList` and `(0 to 2000000).map(x => x -> x).toMap` have similar performance if you give them enough memory (I tried -Xmx4G - 4 Gigabytes). `toMap` implementation is a lot about cloning, so a lot of memory is being "allocated"/"deallocated". So, in case of memory starvation GC is becoming overactive.

When I tried to run `(0 to 2000000).toList` with 128Mb - it took several seconds, but `(0 to 2000000).map(x => x -> x).toMap` took at least 2 minutes with 10% GC activity (VisualVM), and died with out of memory.

However, when I tried `-Xmx4G` both were pretty fast.

---

P.S. What `toMap` does is repeatedly adding an element to a prefix tree, so it has to clone (`Array.copy`) a lot per every element: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.scala#L321.

So, `toMap` is repeatedly (2000000 times) doing `updated0`, which in its turn doing an `Array.copy` pretty often, which requires lots of memory allocations, which (in low-memory case) causes GC to go MarkAndSweep (slow garbage collection) most of the time (as far as I can see from jconsole).

---

Solution: Whether increase the memory (`-Xmx`/`-Xms` JVM parameters) or if you need more complex operations on your data-set use something like Apache Spark (or any batch-oriented map-reduce framework) to process your data in a distributed way.

Comment: I know the `.toMap` is ti e consuming. But, if yo see the example the operation is only done for each entry not amount the list.

Comment: I have been doing some profiling an looks like every time is collected as `Map [String, String]` and the map is passed to the object (for each of the 2 millions entries) some transformation from char [] to String is performed.

Comment: the actual code I'm trying to run as I said in my example is the following:

Comment: @ypriverol it's not that `.toMap` is time consuming, it's that maps use a lot of memory. If you keep the instances of `MyObject` around, then your first snipped requires _a lot_ more memory to run than your second one.